# Books for Ruby On Rails With Facebook Platform!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebooker

Hey guys! do you know good books for Ruby On Rails With Facebook Platform. please suggest some good books for Ruby On Rails With Facebook Platform!

Comment: What do you intend by "Ruby On Rails With Facebook Platform" ?

Comment: I need understand basic facebook app and gem community with facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two good screencasts about using the Facebooker gem

- From peepcode
- From PragmaticProgrammers

However, Facebooker gem for Rails3 gives some problems. And debugging a facebook app is not very well documented. There is a new Facebook gem which might be worth a look too: [koala](http://github.com/arsduo/koala)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at : [Developing Facebook Platform Applications with Rails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356123) ,

Comment: wow, there is a book for fb + rails!